# Reversing order of key in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

Given that CockroachDB stores my table in its primary key, how do I reverse the ordering of a primary key column, to optimize reading it in descending sort order?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the order in which primary keys are sorted by including `DESC` for the column, e.g. `CREATE TABLE tbl (a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY (a DESC, b);`